# Does upgrading a WCF service from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 change the contract?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, asp.net-3.5, upgrade, asp.net-4.0

If I upgrade a WCF Web Service from .NET 3.5 to 4.0, making no other changes, is there any risk of a change to the contract exposed to the outside world?  ie. Will my consumers need to reconsume the WSDL?

If so, is there anything I can do to stop that happening?

**EDIT**: An example of the kind of thing I'm talking about.

We have been using something like this for a while
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx

I may be reading this wrong but when I upgraded the server and reconsumed from the client, the Reference.cs changed so that

```
public MyNamespace.MembershipUser RemoteMembershipProvider_CreateUser(out System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status, string providerName, string applicationName, string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey) {
    return base.Channel.RemoteMembershipProvider_CreateUser(out status, providerName, applicationName, username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey);
}
```

changed to

```
public MyNamespace.MembershipUser RemoteMembershipProvider_CreateUser(out MyNamespace.MembershipCreateStatus status, string providerName, string applicationName, string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey) {
    return base.Channel.RemoteMembershipProvider_CreateUser(out status, providerName, applicationName, username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey);
}
```

Note the change in namespace for MembershipCreateStatus.

(and no, I don't really have a namespace called MyNamespace)

Am I wrong in thinking that if I hadn't reconsumed, it would have stopped working?

And if not, what is the specific thing that has change and how many other cases will it effect?  Just framework enums?  Or more than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be any issues - after all, all that travels between the client and the server is the serialized message.

The client really doesn't care what OS or .NET version the server is on - as long as the message can be understood and interpreted.

As long as *you* don't change anything, you should be just fine!

Comment: The serialised message relies on class names and namespaces, some of which are auto-generated by the framework.  That is my concern.  Not to suggest you're wrong, I'm just saying there's more to it than I have control over.

Comment: Xml namespaces will not change so serialization will not be broken.

Comment: @Ladislav - Looks like you're right. It's the client side of the framework that changed. Thanks to both of you